# This relative module was not found?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I tried running `npm run serve`, and it came back with this error:

> This relative Module was not found:
>
> ```
> *./components/Map.vue
> ```

It exists, and I'm pretty sure I've linked the pages right. How do I correct this?

My config looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    home: {
      
      entry: './src/components/main.js',
      
      template: './src/pages/home/App.vue',
      
      filename: './src/pages/home/App.vue',
      
      title: 'Home Page',
      
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'Home']
    },
    map: {
      
      entry: './src/pages/map/main.js',
      
      template: './src/pages/map/App.vue',
      
      filename: './src/pages/map/App.vue',
      
      title: 'Map',
      
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'Map']
      },
  }
}
```

Am I linking things wrong?

edit:

I have changed my templating based on another answer given on here to the a similar question. Now it's telling me:

These dependencies were not found:

- C:\Users\xadri\OneDrive\Documents\Adrian Code Projects\demo2\demo2\demo2\src\pages\Home\main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.5:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/pages/Home/main.js
- C:\Users\xadri\OneDrive\Documents\Adrian Code Projects\demo2\demo2\demo2\src\pages\Map\main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.5:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/pages/Map/main.js

And is saying I can download them.

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'index': {
      entry: './src/pages/Home/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Home',
      chunks: [ 'chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index' ]
    },
    'map': {
      entry: './src/pages/Map/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Map',
      chunks: [ 'chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'about' ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely caused by the invalid config you currently have.

From the [docs for `pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages):

- `template` should point to an `.html` file (not a `.vue` file)
- `entry` should be a `.js` file (that imports a `.vue` file)
- `filename` should be the output filename in the output folder (don't link it back to the original source files)

Answer (score 0):

use @ before import yours modules, like it:

```
import BntPayment from '@/components/BntPayment.vue'
```

the @ should fix your issue, if it doesn't works do like this

```
import BntPayment from './components/BntPayment'
```